EA: Undo checkout or Check-in commands invoked on this model by user 'xxx', is not yet complete.It is recommended that you wait until it completes
I am facing following error while doing check-in in the Enterprise architect.
ERROR: Undo checkout or Check-in commands invoked on this model by user 'xxxxxxx', is not yet complete.It is recommended that you wait until it completes.
Note:
Undo check out option in the EA has been disabled and Tortoise SVN is used for check out and checkin
I have tried steal lock and Resynch with VC provider options, but still the issue exist

You'll probably have to do a SVN cleanup, and then resynch.

I have done the SVN cleanup but it is not working

if nothing else works, you can clear the package flags in the table t_package

How to clear the package flags in the table t_package, is it in svn or EA?

t_table is a table in the EA database, but if you have to ask, you should probably ask someone with more experience to do it for you.
